# IIS WebSite Connection Timeout during Tests for 5-15 minutes

Tags: iis, selenium-chromedriver

I am experiencing next issue:
I have an AspNetCore website that is hosted on Windows Server 2012 IIS 2019.
I am running automated tests(Selenium, Chrome webdriver) for this website from any another server or PC and sometimes(not every time) after about 4 minutes i am getting Connection Timeout Error.
I am getting this error through Chrome Webdriver, Chrome, but website is accessible through any another PC/Server or even IE on the same server.
This continues for 5 to 15 minutes and after it is back again, i can access the website, i can run the tests.
Looks like something is blocking IP/Web browser from IIS.

1. I am running tests in parallel(4 threads).
2. I am running the same kind of tests for another website(which is not Core, just regular .Net Framework) and never had such issue with it.
3. I've checked DNS resolution - everything is fine, am getting the same error even with it hardcoded in hosts
4. I've disabled server firewall at all - did not work
5. There is no additional Antivirus protection except Windows Defender
6. There is no AVG set up on the server
7. I've tried different Servers, PCs and Chrome versions - still the same error happens from time to time.
8. Windows Event Log has nothing that can be linked to this issue.

Any help is extremely appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the connection timeout error message? I cannot figure out what kind of connection it is. But most of connection timeout in asp.net core are sql connection timeout.

Comment: https://ibb.co/W67qs7s here is the browser screenshot. No SQL Connection Timeout in the logs. No error logs, web site still is working fine for the different browser, but not this one. For 5-10 minutes it is returning only this error for any request to this domain

Comment: The screenshot cannot display. You can add it in this thread directory.https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7CCB.png